# Increase every consecutive for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop

For now I have:

```
Mat avgImg(480, 640, CV_32FC3, Scalar()); // Create and zero initialize
Mat capturedImg;
for (framenumb = 0; framenumb < 10; ++framenumb)
{
    // avgImg.create(480, 640, CV_32FC3); // Don't create each time!
    capturedImg = images[framenumb];
    cv::accumulate(capturedImg, avgImg);
}
avgImg = avgImg / 100;
avgImg.convertTo(avgImg, CV_8UC3);
imshow("averaged", avgImg);
```

How can I make it so that the `for`loop values will increase every time it finishes looping. For example, after 10 images are accumulated and averaged, the loop will then automatically change to `for (framenumb = 10; framenumb < 20; ++framenumb)`to take the next 10 images and so on.

Comment: How would you know when to stop?

Comment: Keep track of the number of times the loop has been reachedin another variable, and change the loop to `for(framenumb = 10*number_of_times; framenumb< number_of_times*10 + 10; ++framenumb)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something as simple as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
    Mat avgImg(480, 640, CV_32FC3, Scalar()); // Create and zero initialize
    Mat capturedImg;
    for (framenumb = 10 * i; framenumb < (10 * i) + 10; ++framenumb) {
        // avgImg.create(480, 640, CV_32FC3); // Don't create each time!
        capturedImg = images[framenumb];
        cv::accumulate(capturedImg, avgImg);
    }

    avgImg = avgImg / 100;
    avgImg.convertTo(avgImg, CV_8UC3);
    imshow("averaged", avgImg);
}
```

Where `NUM` is the number of images divided by 10.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the answer. However, when I tested it today with 99 pictures, it just showed me 99 images instead of 9 averaged images. The code seems to be correct so I don't have an idea why this problem occurs

Comment: Oh nvm, turns out I just forgot to include [framenumb] for capturedImg